# Suppose $F: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous functions. If $f$ and $g$ are measurable, then

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Suppose $F: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous functions. If $f$ and $g$ are measurable, then $h(x) = F( f(x), g(x) ) $ is also measurable.

**Proof:**

For all $a$, $ \{ x : h(x) > a \} = \{ x : (f(x),g(x)) \in G_a \} $ where $G_a := \{ (u,v) : F(u,v) > a \} = F^{-1}((a, \infty))$. Since $F$ is continuous, then given any $(a, \infty)$, we must have $F^{-1}((a, \infty))$ open set. Since open sets are union of open rectangles on $\mathbb{R}^2$, then it must be the case that
$$ G_a = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n,b_n) \times (c_n,d_n) $$ Therefore, Can we say the next step follows from the above? Im having trouble proving this holds. Can someone help me?

$$ \{ x : h(x) > a \} = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \{ x : f(x) \in (a_n,b_n) \} \cap \{ x : g(x) \in (c_n, d_n) \} $$

And the above is measurable since it is union of measurable sets, thence $F$ must be measurable.

Comment: Note that `\begin{proof} ... \end{proof}` is not recognized by MathJax.

Comment: I've also fixed a minor typo in the first line of the proof; I hope you don't mind.

Comment: I think you mean $ \{ x : h(x) > a \} = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \{ x : f(x) \in (a_n,b_n) \} \cap \{ x : g(x) \in (c_n, d_n) \} $?

Comment: you are absolutely right. It was a typo.

Comment: I thought so; I fixed it in your question.  Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
h(x) > a &\iff 
(f(x),g(x)) \in G_a
\\
&\iff
(f(x),g(x)) \in (a_n,b_n) \times (c_n, d_n) \text{ for some } n
\\
&\iff f(x) \in (a_n,b_n) \text{ and } g(x) \in (c_n, d_n) \text{ for some } n
\\
\end{align*}

So

\begin{align*}
\{x : h(x) > a\} = \bigcup_n \{x : f(x) \in (a_n,b_n)\} \cap \{x : g(x) \in (c_n, d_n)\}
\end{align*}